# Customised method for List collection based on a type

Tags: c#

Is there a way of extending the C# List class that would allow me to attach a custom method specific for one type?

In my example I have a List of `LatestNews` objects. Each of these contains a property of type `Category`.

What I want to do is attach a custom method to the `List<>` that would return all unique `Category` objects within the collection of `LatestNews`.

I have the following working using Generics but I noticed that if I then declare a `List<>` of a different type (i.e. string) this method is made available.

```
public static List<LatestNewsCategory> getUniqueCategories<T>(this IList<T> list) 
{
    List<LatestNewsCategory> catList = new List<LatestNewsCategory>();
    List<LatestNews> myNewsList = (List<LatestNews>)list;

    foreach (LatestNews news in myNewsList)
    {
        if (catList.Find(LatestNewsCategory => LatestNewsCategory.ID == news.Category.ID) == null)
        {
            catList.Add(news.Category);
        }
    }

    return catList;
}
```

Is there a different approach I should be taking with this?

Should I maybe look at creating a custom class that extends List instead?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the cast fail? `List<T>`'s generic type parameter is invariant.

Comment: @dcastro - It compiled fine and I'm getting a result but the main reason for the cast was so I could work with the properties of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your generic type in the signature.

Change it so something like this:

```
public static List<LatestNewsCategory> getUniqueCategories(this IList<LatestNews> list)
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Oddly I thought I'd tried this before! I've added your suggestion to my method this morning and the intellisense is now working correctly. I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Parametrize your list with `LatestNews` type if you want this extension to be available only to list of `LatestNews`:

```
public static List<LatestNewsCategory> getUniqueCategories(
    this IList<LatestNews> list) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Side note 1 - we use PascalCase names for public members, e.g. GetUniqueCategories

Side note 2 - you can use LINQ to get distinct categories from list of latest news:

```
return list.Select(n => n.Category)
           .GroupBy(c => c.ID)
           .Select(g => g.First())
           .ToList();
```

Or if you have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overridden on `LatestNewsCategory` type, then you can simply

```
return list.Select(n => n.Category).Distinct().ToList();
```

Side note 3 - you can create extension for `IEnumerable<LatestNews>` thus you just enumerating list items.

Comment: Thanks for the side notes Sergey. You can probably gather C# is not my main language! I'm fairly new to it and used to working in Camel Case approach. Old habits are hard shift sometimes. I'll have a look at your LINQ approach and other suggestions today as well. Thanks again for the feedback, it's appreciated. James

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to derive? If you do this, try to keep it on the generic side of things, like this:

```
class SpecializedList<T> extends List<T>
{
    // put your specialized generic<T> methods here
}
```

That may be a good thing to reuse code, but sincerely this makes more sense when you have say 2 or 3 specialized methods.